# What constitutes a valid spatial layer when connecting QGIS to MySQL?

Tags: qgis, mysql

I'm trying to work with a MySQL 5.5 table using QGIS 1.8.  I can do "Add Vector Layer", choose "Database", and successfully connect to the MySQL connection I previously set up.  QGIS shows me a "Select vector layers to add" dialog that lists the tables in my database, including the one I want to use which shows a "Geometry type" of "Point" (which is correct, there's a POINT column in that table).  When I highlight that table from the list and click OK I get an error message:

`The layer MySQL:[redacted connection info] is not a valid layer and can not be added to the map`

Is there something that needs to be done to make a MySQL table a "valid layer" other than making sure that it has a geometry field (like a point)?

Comment: Can you make a connection directly with ogr?  Try using ogrinfo to see what it tells you about the table.  The syntax is to use is at the bottom of this page:  http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_mysql.html

Answer (score 1):

Does your MySQL data have a MySQL spatial index? 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html
Additionaly do you have spatial extensions installed for MySQL?
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/spatial-extensions.html
I don't know if this is the problem, but without more information I will offer it as a possible solution.